# Воспроизведение http-аудиопотока с сервера от icecast

Tags: android, kotlin, http, icecast

Есть сервер на icecast2, с которого идет трансляция радио. Поток в формате http, [ссылка](http://62.109.9.171:8000/autodj) на него. Есть так же расширение для [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/radoo-leader-tv-for-my-yo/eembchlegaabflfldipadjdneenljdke?hl=ru) и андроид-версия, основанная на [android-icecast-broadcast](https://github.com/fatihsokmen/android-icecast-broadcast). Вот как раз андроид-версию я и хочу переделать. Хоть и воспроизведение работает безупречно, но сама программа получается чересчур большой.

Вот мой код, прога запускается без крашей, но воспроизведение не идет ни на апи 14-15, ни на 21-22, ни на 24

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val mp = MediaPlayer()
        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://62.109.9.171:8000/autodj")
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mp.setAudioAttributes(
                        AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                .build())
            } else {
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            }
            mp.setOnPreparedListener { mp.start() }
            mp.prepareAsync()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.isLooping = true;
        mp.start()
//        println(mp.trackInfo)
    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.ursna.radio">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Radio">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге все таки решил все через ExoPlayer. Добавил зависимость:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.12.2'
```

Инициализировал все нужное:

```
    val context = this
            var isPaused = true
val playButton: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton)
            val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
            player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("http://62.109.9.171:8000/autodj")))
            player.prepare()
```

Назначил слушателя на кнопку `play/pause:`

```
playButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (isPaused) {
                player.play()
                isPaused = false
            } else if (!isPaused) {
                player.pause()
                isPaused = true
            }
            updateButton(isPaused, theme, playButton)
        }
```

Ну и методы `theme()`(Запускать перед `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`) и `updateButton()` если кому-то надо(у меня есть 2 иконки play и 2 иконки pause черного и белого цвета):

```
fun theme() {
val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val theme = prefs.getBoolean("theme_key", true)
        if (theme) {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_NoActionBar)
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_NoActionBar)
        }
}
```

Проверка на белую тему уже после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`:

```
if (!theme) {
            playButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_dark)
        }
```

Ну и метод для смены иконки play/pause на кнопке

```
fun updateButton(isPaused: Boolean, theme: Boolean, playButton: ImageButton) {
        if(!isPaused) {
            if (theme) {
                playButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause)
            } else {
                playButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_dark)
            }
        }
        if(isPaused) {
            if (theme) {
                playButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play)
            } else {
                playButton.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_dark)
            }
        }
    }
```